# Body-Parser doesen't parse Dates back

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, axios

Following Szenario:

- The api server is sending an object with dates
- The object gets automatically parsed by express

Problem:

- The dates in the received object are not parsed back into date-objects (they are still strings)

```
[enter image description here][1]
// OBJECT SENDING WITH EXPRESS-API
 res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
      data,
  });

// CONSUMING DATA WITH AXIOS RESPONSE
exports.demos = async (req, res, next) => {
  const response = await axios.get('.../api/v1/endpoint');

// BODY PARSER CONFIG
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' }));
app.use(cookieParser());
```